# Why array can be used as callback

Tags: php

On this page of PHP manual http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php, I found this function spec: `bool session_set_save_handler ( callable $open , callable $close , callable $read , callable $write , callable $destroy , callable $gc )` which indicates all parameters should be a callback. But I also found this example on that page:

```
    class FileSessionHandler
    {
        private $savePath;

        function open($savePath, $sessionName)
        {
            $this->savePath = $savePath;
            if (!is_dir($this->savePath)) {
                mkdir($this->savePath, 0777);
            }

            return true;
        }

        function close()
        {
           ...
        }
        ...
    }
$handler = new FileSessionHandler();
session_set_save_handler(
    array($handler, 'open'),
    array($handler, 'close'),
    array($handler, 'read'),
    array($handler, 'write'),
    array($handler, 'destroy'),
    array($handler, 'gc')
    );
```

Every parameter in the `session_set_save_handler` is an array in which first element is the handler object and second a string.

Why those arrays can be used as callbacks? I referenced Array, callback manuals but found no clue on how this is possible.

Comment: Just click on "Callable" in front of the parameter and you can read in the manual: http://www.php.net/language.types.callable.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php -- second sentence under "passing".

Comment: You write in your question you had read that manual page. So probably it's worth to ask back which part in it about the arrays you have not understood?

Comment: @hakre I just know `callable` means it'll call `call_user_func` on the array parameter.

Comment: No, callable is a *pseudo-type* used in the PHP manual. What it means is written on the manual page I linked in first comment. Do you know what a *Callback Function* is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array($handler, 'open')
```

> Why those arrays can be used as callbacks?

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

because it is a valid callback definition :

```
array($instance,'method')
```

or

```
array($class,'staticMethod')
```

check the exemple#1 type 2 and type 3 in the link provided.

Comment: so `callable` means it'll automatically call `call_user_func` on the array?

Comment: It is just a way to define a "valid" callback.

Answer (score 0):

You may find instructive:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

A fairly wide variety of data can be passed as callables in PHP, including a string containing the name of a global scope or built-in function, a Closure (as of PHP 5.3), or an array which contains either the name of a class and the name of a static method in that class or an object instance and the name of an instance method on that object's class.